# Meteor Accounts - Users Logged Out on Refresh

Tags: meteor, token, resume, accounts

I am using the 'accounts-base' and 'accounts-password' packages and the Accounts.createUser method to create users from a login form (i.e. I am not using the accounts-ui package).

the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users) explains that the user thus created includes a 'services' object

> "containing data used by particular login services. For example, its
>   reset field contains tokens used by forgot password links, and its
>   resume field contains tokens used to keep you logged in between
>   sessions."

This is true and accounts created using my login form all have loginTokens.  However, when I refresh the browser, these tokens are deleted and the user is logged-out.

The documentation appears to suggest that resume tokens are handled automatically by the accounts-base / accounts-password packages.  What have I missed?

```
Accounts.createUser({
      username: username,
      email: username,
      password: password
    }, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        alert(err)
      } else {            
        Router.go('/member/' + Meteor.userId() +'/edit')               
      }
    });
```

creates:

```
 "resume" : 
{ "loginTokens" : 
  [
   {
   "when" : ISODate("2014-04-17T22:13:50.832Z"),
   "hashedToken" : "KstqsW9aHqlw6pjfyQcO6jbGCiCiW3LGAXJaVS9fQ+o=" 
   } 
  ] 
}
```

...but on refresh:

```
"resume" : { "loginTokens" : [ ] } },
```

Comment: `Accounts.createUser` is a server function. How are you accessing the `Router.go` client function in a callback? Mind where you are placing your code...

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_createuser), Account.createUser is available on both client and server.  I am using it on both, for different puposes, but the effect, so far as this question is concrened, is the same:  the user is successfully created, the tokens are created, but refreshing the page in the browser logs out the user and deletes the tokens.  I confess that I am unclear as to what is supposed to happen, but suffice it to say I don't want the user to be logged out when the page is refreshed, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

After an exhaustive audit of my code I found that I was (idiotically) invoking the Accounts.logout method outside the confines of the log-out button event.  It had somehow become 'orphaned' during an earlier re-factoring of the code

So all my fault.